# Determine whether the series diverges or converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I would appreciate help in determining if the following series diverges or converges: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\ln (n+1)-\ln n\right)^{\ln n}$. I know of one approach, but that gets very complicated, and I thought that someone in here might know of a slightly smoother way to do this?

**My approach**: I have started by rewriting the expression to $e^{ln(n)ln(ln(n+1)-ln(n))}$. Then I applied the Limit Chain rule where $g_1(x)=ln(n)ln(ln(n+1)-ln(n))$ and $f_1(u)=e^{u}$ and started with solving $$(1)\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(n)ln(ln(n+1)-ln(n))=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(n)\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(ln(n+1)-ln(n))=\infty\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(ln(n+1)-ln(n))$$

And to solve that I applied the Limit Chain rule again where $g_2(x)=ln(n+1)-ln(n)$ and $f_2(u)=ln(u)$ and started solving $$(2)\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(n+1)-ln(n)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$$

And here I need to apply the Limit Chain rule again where $g_3(x)=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $f_3(u)=ln(u)$ and started solving $$(3)\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1+\frac{1}{n}=1.$$

And only from here I can start computing all $f(u)$, so for $f_3(u)$ we have that $\lim_{u\rightarrow 1}ln(u)=0$. For $f_2(u)$ we have that $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}ln(u)=-\infty$ that we now can put in (1) and get $\infty(-\infty)=-\infty$. Now we can finally determine $f_1(u)=\lim_{u\rightarrow-\infty}e^u=0$ and say that the series is convergent.

Comment: If one knows only that the terms in a series tend to $0$, that's not enough to conclude that the series converges. Hint for another approach: note that $\ln n\ge2$ for all $n\ge8$, and use that in the exponent and the Comparison Test.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{3n^3}-\frac{1}{4n^4}+...\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Then for $n\geq 8$ we have $\ln(n)\geq 2$, and therefore

$$\sum_{n=8}^\infty (\ln(n+1)-\ln(n))^{\ln(n)}\leq \sum_{n=8}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach.  Note that for $x>0$, $0<\log(1+x)\le x$.   Therefore, we have

$$0< \log(n+1)-\log(n)\le \frac1n$$

So, for $n>3$, $\log(n)>1.09$ and hence

$$\left( \log(n+1)-\log(n) \right)^{\log(n)}<\frac1{n^{1.09}}$$

Using the p-test, we conclude that the series of interest converges.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.